# Memory Leaks - Returning NSMutableArray from class method containing Custom Objects

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am using DBManager Class to retrun data from SQlite database. The class contains methods which returns MutableArray by fetching it from database. like bellow ..

```
+ (NSMutableArray *) getSaleForYear : (NSString *) year {

    if ([DBManager openDBConnection]) {

        NSMutableArray * sales = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

        const char *q = "SELECT sales, quarter FROM sale where year like ? order by quarter";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, q, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            if(sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 1, [year UTF8String] , -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK){
                NSLog(@"bind error : %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String: sqlite3_errmsg(database)]);
                return nil;
            }

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                float sale = sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 0);
                    //NSString * quarter = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
                NSString * quarter = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

                ChartData * b1 = [[ChartData alloc] initwithdata:quarter y:sale];
                [sales addObject:b1];
                [b1 release];
                [quarter release];
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
        [DBManager closeDBConnection];
        return [sales autorelease];
    }else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

And I am calling the method like.

```
- (IBAction) getData {

    NSLog(@"getdata");

    if (arr != nil) {
        for (ChartData * cd in arr) {
            [cd release];
        }
        arr = nil;
        [arr release];
    }

    arr = [[DBManager getSaleForYear:@"2010-11"] copy];
    NSLog(@"count %d ", [arr count]);
}
```

This approach is creating memory leaks for iterative calls of the function.
Please suggest cause of the leak and solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You set `arr = nil` before releasing it, this the `[arr release]` has no effect
2. You must not loop through the array and release each object (see fluchtpunkt comment below).
3. No need to check `arr == nil` sending messages to nil is valid.

I'd write:

```
- (IBAction)getData {
    NSLog(@"getdata");

    [arr release];

    arr = [[DBManager getSaleForYear:@"2010-11"] copy];
    NSLog(@"count %d ", [arr count]);
}
```

Comment: The second point should be "you MUST NOT loop...". When the outer array is released each object will be removed from the array and would get another release call. But it was already released manually. -> memory exception

Comment: Thanks, that loop I added just to test if it can solve my problem. As I could not see dealloc of Chartdata being called only for `[arr release]`

Answer (score 1):

you should probably invert these lines of code:

```
arr = nil;
[arr release];
```

this way:

```
[arr release];
arr = nil;
```